# How to copy / download file created in Pyodide in browser?

Tags: python, pyodide

I managed to run Pyodide in browser. I created `hello.txt` file. But how can I access it.

Pyodide 
 https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/blob/master/docs/using_pyodide_from_javascript.md

```
pyodide.runPython('open("hello.txt", "w")')
```

What I tried in chrome devtools?

```
pyodide.runPython('os.chdir("../")')
pyodide.runPython('os.listdir()')
pyodide.runPython('os.path.realpath("hello.txt")')
```

Output for `listdir`

```
["hello.txt", "lib", "proc", "dev", "home", "tmp"]
```

Output for `realpath`

```
"/hello.txt"
```

Also,

```
pyodide.runPython('import platform')
pyodide.runPython('platform.platform()')
```

Output

```
"Emscripten-1.0-x86-JS-32bit"
```

All outputs in chrome devtools console.

It is created in root folder. But how it can be accessed in file explorer or anyway to copy file to Download folder?

Thanks

Comment: https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html

Comment: I am finding solution and got this. May be helpful https://groups.google.com/g/emscripten-discuss/c/xnTzhcsMj4U?pli=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed pyodide operates in an [in-memory (MEMFS) filesystem](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html) created by Emscripten. You can't directly write files to disk from pyodide since it's executed in the browser sandbox.

You can however, pass your file to JavaScript, create a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) out of it and then download it. For instance, using,

```js
let txt = pyodide.runPython(`                  
    with open('/test.txt', 'rt') as fh:
        txt = fh.read()
    txt
`);
const blob = new Blob([txt], {type : 'application/text'});
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.location.assign(url);
```

It should have been also possible to do all of this from the Python side, using the [type conversions](https://pyodide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_conversions.html) included in pyodide, i.e.

```py
from js import Blob, document
from js import window
  
with open('/test.txt', 'rt') as fh:
    txt = fh.read()
    
blob = Blob.new([txt], {type : 'application/text'})
url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob) 
window.location.assign(url)
```

however at present, this unfortunately doesn't work, as it depends on  [pyodide#788](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/issues/788) being resolved first.

Comment: Then it is also possible to send file from local browser to MEMFS?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes, you can also get any object, including a representation of a File, from JS to Python and then write it to MEMFS there https://pyodide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_conversions.html#using-python-objects-from-javascript

Comment: any update on this ? I'm very interested in the solution to save tmp files

Comment: The link to the documentation by @rth in the comment above dated Nov2'20 20:51 is outdated. I think it should be https://pyodide.org/en/latest/usage/type-conversions.html?highlight=javascript#type-translations now.

Comment: This now works for me in firefox running osx sonoma 14.1

Answer (score 3):

I have modified the answer by [rth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1791279/rth). It will download file with the name of file.

```js
let txt = pyodide.runPython(`                  
    with open('/test.txt', 'rt') as fh:
        txt = fh.read()
    txt
`);

const blob = new Blob([txt], {type : 'application/text'});
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = url;
downloadLink.download = "test.txt";
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
```

Comment: Although technically, this assumes a lot more than @rth answer, I like it.