# Why is the wep page with pyodide and python module failed to load on iOS, but it can load on Android and Desktop?

Tags: python, anki, pyodide

I have create a simple app using pyodide to export [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) deck from csv, tsv or text file. It is working fine on desktop and android. But the page failed to load on iOS. What is the reason and how can I solve this?

Links to my webpage containing pyodide.
https://infinyte7.github.io/Anki-Export-Deck-tkinter/

Source code of the webpage
https://github.com/infinyte7/Anki-Export-Deck-tkinter/tree/master/docs

Thanks

Comment: can you provide any debug information using [Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or try to put your code in a try/catch block and show errors by printing it in a `div` or by `alert()`

Comment: btw, as far as I know `open()` won't work in browser. check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669355/how-to-copy-download-file-created-in-pyodide-in-browser)

Comment: `open()` in pyodide opens files in the virtual in memory filsystem created by emscripten..

Comment: If you are using Safari, it's a known issue for now https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/issues/721 Otherwise could you try with the dev version? Replace `v0.15.0` by `dev` in the URL.

Comment: I tried the dev version but still not working. I tried it chrome and safari on iOS.

Comment: I will provide the debug info. `Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Out of executable memory in function at index 10175(anonymous function) @ [native code]:1promiseReactionJob   @ [native code]:1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing this on various iphone I came to know that it is not working for iOS 11 & 12. I getting following errors

```
iOS 11
[native code]:1 Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Out of executable memory in function at index 14480

iOS 12
pyodide.asm.js:8 Unhandled Promise Rejection: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

But for iOS 13 & 14 it seems to be working.